# parse console output text with javascript

Tags: regex, parsing, text, console

What is the best way to parse a console output like ?

```
"data": [
    "  TCP    127.0.0.1:3000         127.0.0.1:9595         HERGESTELLT     4432",
    "  TCP    127.0.0.1:3000         127.0.0.1:9596         HERGESTELLT     4432",
    "  TCP    127.0.0.1:9584         127.0.0.1:3000         WARTEND         0",
    "  TCP    127.0.0.1:9585         127.0.0.1:3000         WARTEND         0",
    "  TCP    127.0.0.1:9595         127.0.0.1:3000         HERGESTELLT     4588",
    "  TCP    127.0.0.1:9596         127.0.0.1:3000         HERGESTELLT     4588",

  ]
```

I need trimed strings splited in sub arrays for each item. The problem is each item is different in length. I guess the best way to parse it is a regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.item.split(/  +/)
```

String.split accepts regex ^^